# Why does my console application disappear immediately

Tags: c#, console

I've made a Console Application is Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
This is what i've added to my code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
```

When I'm debugging this program, the program close immediatly!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The program ran successfully to completion - what did you *expect* it to do?

Comment: i ran into this problem so many times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `Console.ReadLine()` to the end of the `Main` method, this will make the console wait until the user sends any input to the console and then it will exit.

Answer (score 2):

Al the existing answers are correct, but Ctrl-F5 (instead of just F5 in VS) to run will also have the effect of waiting for a keystroke.

EDIT

The above will not allow you to *debug* as such, but you don't have a breakpoint in there anyway.  Pressing F10 will step through the program line by line.

Comment: This is not what I want, this doesn't work for my .exe

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the only statement you have just prints a line and the execution of program is finished and program is exited. Use [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Line to stop window to get disappear. Use read line will exit program when Enter key is pressed.

You can use [ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to do like "Press any key to continue..." The will cause the program to exit when any key is pressed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Console.ReadLine();` after `WriteLine` method, So your application will wait user to input. After user pressed any keys, Your application will disappear.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

This will await a keystroke before closing the program.

Answer (score 0):

all of the above is correct. Typically, Console.ReadKey() is used for control purpose instead logic processing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    string line = Console.ReadKey();
}
```

you can get more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)